# Google Play Services with Unity - Sign in results in nothing

Tags: c#, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

So I have been recently trying to add Google Play Game Services to a project my buddy and I are working on.

I figured I would start with the sign in, as that is necessary for anything else that we wanted to add like achievements and leaderboards.
Anyway, I have published a closed Alpha to the google play store with my buddies dev and my own dev emails as the testers. I have set up my OAuth2 Client ID, SHA 1, AndroidManifest file, and other Game Services we are hoping for.

I then in Unity included the most recent Google Play Games Plugin (0.9.50), and set up the Resources and Client ID into our project. I of course have my Key and such for a Signed APK for our Closed Alpha test.

I then set up a button for Sign In within our scene, and have my code set up as follows:

```
void Start ()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .RequestEmail()
        .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
        .RequestIdToken()
        .Build();

    //DEBUGGING ONLY
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    // Does nothing either . . . .
   Social.Instance.Authenticate((bool success) => { SignInCallback(success); }, false);
}

public void SignIn()
{
    _signInNotification.text = "WARMER";

    if (!PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        _signInNotification.text = "SIGNING IN";
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { SignInCallback(success); });
    }
    else
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();

        _signInNotification.text = "OUT";
    }
}

private void SignInCallback(bool success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("(Something) Signed in!");

        _signInNotification.text = "Signed In as : " + Social.localUser.userName;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("(Something) Sign-In Failed!");

        _signInNotification.text = "Sign-In Failed!";
    }
}[/code]
```

I have some text that lets me know what part of the code was accessed or run. The sign in button calls the SignIn() function, but only the text 'WARMER' is shown. The Social.localUser.Authenticate() function never seems to be called.

I have tried multiple solutions, changes, variations, etc. However when I click the SignIn button, absolutely nothing happens. No error, no warnings, no text saying Sign-In Failed, nothing.

Not quite sure what I am missing, any ideas would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

One problem I've realized with debugging Google Play Services problems is that the errors that pop up are from a separate activity, since the sign-in prompt is outside the app. You are probably getting an error response, but it's not from your program. Because of this, you might need to disable any filters in your console to see all errors (if you have Android Studio, the logcat should show all responses from a plugged-in device when it's set to No Filters).

In my case, the plugin had an AndroidManifest file (GooglePlayGames/Plugins/Android/GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin folder) where the APP_ID had a value with a space in front of it. I believe this was an old workaround to convert the value to a string, but now the app required that it was a numeric value, so deleting the space solved my problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using Unity, I am not sure if I would be able to check my game via Android Studio using the logcat. 

I noticed the spaces you mentioned in my Manifest file and removed them, thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately, it still hasn't solved my problem, but am hoping it has put me one step closer!

Comment: Even if you are not running the game directly from Android Studio, if you have Android Studio, you can still just plug in the device and check the logcat for any output the device is producing while the game is running, as long as you enabled debugging permissions through your device's Developer settings.

Also, the "space" fix may or may not work based on different plugin versions, so just keep that in mind as you are trying out other solutions.

Comment: I finally got it working. I guess I published the alpha a bit too early. I created just a plain Game Services game and found the SHA 1 fingerprint via the keytool executable and everything worked smoothly. EXCEPT, now for some reason one account succeeds authentication while a different account fails.... I don't quite understand why..

Comment: So using the logcat tool, I was able to find out the errors I am getting. It currently gives my a SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED and then follows with a AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with failure. 

I've double checked my Manifest files, package name, SHA 1 fingerprint, they all seem to be matching. Interesting problem. The weird part about this was my account originally used to log in, but when I tried again it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @aromans, did you manage to fix this? I'm having the exact same problem as you had here, with sign in not doing anything and my account initially used to sign in but now nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To set up Google Play Game Services we followed the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and it guided us through all the needed steps. 
What we found when we couldn't log in is that while testing your application your OAuth 2.0 client ID (on Google API Console > Credentials) should use the SHA-1 Signing-certificate fingerprint key from your Upload certificate and when it's time to publish the SHA-1 key should be from the App signing certificate. Both certificates can be found on your Google Play Console > All applications (choose the correct one) > Release management > App signing.